# What is set_current_state() macro in kernel thread?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, scheduling

While studying kernel threading I came across this piece of code:

```
while(!kthread_should_stop()){ 
  set_current_state(TASK_RUNNING);
  
  /* Doing some stuff here */

  set_current_state(TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
  msleep(1000);
```

What is the macro ***set_current_state*** used for and what are the parameters that are being passed?

Answer (score 7):

As per this [LinuxJournal](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8144) article

> `set_current_state()` changes the state of the currently executing process from `TASK_RUNNING` to `TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE`.

Here, `TASK_RUNNING` and `TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE` are two *states* of a process.

- `TASK_RUNNING` -- A ready-to-run process has the state TASK_RUNNING.
- `TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE`  -- A state of the process, with which is `schedule()` is called, the process is moved *off the run-queue*.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define set_current_state(state_value)                  \
do {                                \
    debug_normal_state_change((state_value));       \
    smp_store_mb(current->__state, (state_value));      \
} while (0)
```

1. Modify the state of the thread
2. barrier

And __set_current_state The difference is that the  "dmb"